# A gas close to zero Kelvin

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider an adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas that work is done against friction or a piston. Since no heat exchange can occur the gas keep on losing energy and its temperature decreases and the gas molecules getting further and further apart. In principle the temperature can get down to a few degrees Kelvin, close to zero K.

Is it possible that a gas can still be a gas at such a low temperature?

Comment: Have you heard of [Helium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium) (triple point ~2K at standard conditions)?

Comment: I think I need to make it clear that the temperature is very close to 0K that the molecules can hardly translate.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the (relatively informal) definitions:

- **Gas**: A substance whose molecules fill the space available to it
- **Liquid**: A substance whose molecules form a fixed volume but have no fixed shape
- **Solid**: A substance whose molecules resist both changes to shape and volume, who do not flow, and do not expand to take the shape or volume of the container.

So based on those definitions, although imprecise as they may be, there is no requirement to be at a particular temperature. In theory, once the molecules reach $0 K$ and they are no longer moving, they will also no longer fill the shape of the container nor will they expand to take up new volume and so they must be a solid. But as soon as it has any temperature and the molecules are once again translating, it could be a solid, a liquid, or a gas.

Comment: In looking at those loose definitions, I wonder how a plasma fits in.

Comment: Thanks. I just wonder can a substance close to 0K be called a solid as there is a lot of space not filled up and it is easy to be compress (i.e. not resistant to both changes to shape and volume)

Comment: @KyleKanos Loosely an ionized gas. When there is sufficient $kT$ around for atomic ionization inter-atomic forces of all types in are real danger of being overwhelmed. I'm quite sure they are completely obliterated in most cases, so now I'm hoping some smart arse will pull up a exceptional case just to confound me. *I Double **Dog** Dare you!*

Comment: @KyleKanos Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_%28physics%29), " Like gas, plasma does not have a definite shape or a definite volume unless enclosed in a container; unlike gas, under the influence of a magnetic field, it may form structures such as filaments, beams and double layers."

Comment: @user48904 Fortunately we will probably never know since we can't every actually get to $0 K$ :)

Comment: @tpg2114: so you''re saying that it's like the odd cousin we all have: just doesn't really fit in anywhere.

Comment: @dmckee: I know what a plasma is, I was just trying to see if Tim had a place for it in his loose definitions.

Comment: @KyleKanos It's more like a "pretty awesome gas." And in actuality, I've always kind of objected to considering it an entirely new state of matter. It's really just a slightly different already-existing state of matter. We don't have magnetic solids as a state of matter, why have magnetic gasses?

Comment: @KyleKanos Some people just refer plasma as the forth type of state.

Comment: @KyleKanos Well, I didn't think you didn't know, but I use the same loose taxonomy  with the above definition for plasma. The only thing is that I've never know for sure that you can't get significant ionization in non-gaseous materials. I'm trying to pull someones obscure knowledge out into the open here. 'Course it has occurred to me that good conductors are arguable a mixed solid/plama case.